# A (non corny) mathematical puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

### What's the nine-letter word I'm looking for? It starts with O.

---

[image]

```
      x x x x x x x x x x x x
      x x x x x x x x x x x x
      x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

Comment: I think I have an answer but it has ten letters rather than nine. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what word you had in mind, but the correct answer has been given by Amoz.

Comment: @hexomino Was it also octahedron what you had in mind?

Comment: @LukasRotter yes, it was, seems I was way off

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for the word

> OPERATORS!

Explanation: Let's take the image of X's:
[image: Xs]

> Overlay the provided shapes:
>  [image: overlay]

> Identify any X's that are NOT corners (non-corny), that is, they are not under a corner of any shape:
>  [image: non-corny]

> Then let's play "connect the dots" in each of the 4 shapes:
>  [image: dots]

And we have just drawn the

> 4 basic mathematical OPERATORS, + / x and -, the 9 letter term which must be the final answer!

Comment: This is indeed the intended answer. Nice job!